# How to create macro variable to export data in SAS?

Tags: sas

thanks for your help! The Question: In your EPG1V2 (or EPG194) folder, open libname.sas. Create a macro variable named outpath that stores the filepath to your EPG1V2/output folder:
%let outpath=filepath-to-output-folder;
Run the code.

My Code:
`libname PG1 "/home/u61719204/EPG1V2/data";proc export data= ______(not sure)? %let outpath=/home/uXXXXXXX/EPG1V2/output; dbms=csv replace; run;`

LOG: FILE= or TABLE= is required and must be specified.

How do I write code for this question? I am stuck here. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment says to assign the path to a macro variable.  That assignment should probably occur before the `LIBNAME` statement.

```
* the filepath to your EPG1V2/output folder;
%let outpath = /home/u61719204/EPG1V2/data;
```

Then the options of the EXPORT procedure can utilize the macro variable.  The assignment you posted does not discuss which data set is to be exported, so consider SASHELP.CLASS as an example.  Resolve the macro variable as part of the file= option value.

```
proc export data=sashelp.class replace file="&outpath./class.csv" dbms=csv;
run;
```

Note: Macro variables do not get resolved when inside single quotes.